# Save partial data (update) with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So I'm trying to do an update to an Entity model but it's not going as well as I'd like. I'm only trying to update a few fields in my model, but when I have the following code run, I get a `SqlException` complaining that there are fields (that I'm not trying to edit) that do not allow nulls. It's seeming like it's trying to create a new row in the database, instead of just updating the existing one? Not too sure what to make of it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Budget(Proposal proposal)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Proposals.Attach(proposal);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(proposal, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = proposal.ProposalID});
    }

    return View(proposal);
}
```

Here's the `SqlException` that I'm getting: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Ulid', table 'casurg2_dev2.dbo.Proposals'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated."

And here's the view in question: http://pastie.org/7984222

Comment: Please post the full `SqlException` details.  If it's trying to create a new record it's probably because you're expecting `proposal` to contain values - but the model binding may not have worked.  Post the value of the `proposal` at this point.

Comment: What is `Ulid` to the `Proposal` Entity? Is it the primary key? a non-nullable foreign key?  Still sounds like a model binding issue.  If you put a breakpoint in this method - what are the values of the fields in question?  You could post the Proposal Entity Class code - that may help too.

Comment: Updated the question with the exception.

Comment: `Ulid` is just a plain field, and it does not allow nulls. `proposal` in the code has everything at null, except the correct ID and any data I put in the right fields.

Comment: everything at null... that's not good ;)  Time to post the view code in question; see if we can spot any model binding issues

Comment: Updated with the view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the source didn't really help as much (and btw - this is SO, you can paste your code here; no need to be pasting it elsewhere ;)

I did ask for the class definition of the Proposal entity aswell... but in it's absence i can only suggest [at a guess] that your put the original value of Ulid as a hidden field alongside your `ProposalId` like such:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProposalID)  
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ulid)
```

so that the model binder can wire it up correctly on the post.

There are 2 ways i can think of to get around the effort with all the hiddenfor's

- Use the Add Controller Wizard to set the template to EntityFramework - then modify the related View code.  throw away what you don't want etc.

[image]

- Change the Action method to re-fetch the Proposal record (using its ProposalId) and then bind the changed data to it.  This is not the kinda advice i should be giving (an extra, unnecessary round trip to the db)

  ```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Budget(Proposal proposal)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var proposalToMerge = db.Proposals.Find(proposal.ProposalId);
            UpdateModel(proposalToMerge);
            // don't need this anymore as entity instance is being tracked
            // db.Proposals.Attach(proposalToMerge );
            // db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(proposalToMerge , EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = proposal.ProposalID});
        }

        return View(proposal);
    }
  ```

Or summing like that.  Untested.

Comment: Here's the `Proposal` model, it's coming from a EDMX. http://i.imgur.com/4L0im2n.png

Obviously, there are a ton of fields, is there a way that I can make this work without having to have a ton of HiddenFor's all over the place?

Comment: Sweet deal, I did the second part to change around the controller method. Thanks for all the help :)